# Given that $n > 3$ and $z$ is a Gaussian integer, when can $z^n \pm z$ be a rational integer?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I came across the following conjecture. If you have any thoughts on how to approach it, let me know.

**Conjecture.** For any integer $n > 3$ and any Gaussian integer $z$ that is not a unit, if $z^n - z$ or $z^n + z$ is a rational integer, then $z$ is a rational integer.

Comment: At least there are at most finitely many such $z$ in each degree; this is due to Siegel's theorem applied to the fix of the 2-set stabilizer in the splitting field of $x^n\pm x-y\in Q(y)[x]$; hypothetical solutions $z$ would in particular yield quadratic factors of the above polynomial, i.e. integral points on the curve corresponding to the 2-set stabilizer, but this curve is not given by a "Siegel function" (for $n=5$, the genus can directly be calculated as $1$, and in all other degrees $>3$, already the ramification pattern at infinity is not consistent with that of a Siegel function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question can be rephrased: Find the integers $n > 3$ for which there exist Gaussian integers $z$ such that
$z^n \pm z = \overline{z}^n \pm \overline{z}$. Rewriting the equation as $(z^n -\overline{z}^n)/(z-\overline{z}) = \mp 1$, one recognizes an instance of the problem of finding the  terms of a Lucas sequence with no  primitive divisors. The complete answer to an even more general problem (Lehmer sequences instead of Lucas sequences) was given by Bilu, Hanrot, Voutier  [J. Reine Angew. Math.
539, 75-122 (2001)](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crll.2001.080/html)  and Abouzaid  [J. Théor. Nombres Bordx.
18, No. 2, 299--313 (2006)](https://jtnb.centre-mersenne.org/articles/10.5802/jtnb.545/) .  To settle the conjecture, it suffices to  look up the  tables in these papers .

Comment: your response led me to write a paper on completely solving the Thue equation |t_p(x, y)|=1, where t_p(x,y) is the homogenization of the minimal polynomial of tan(Pi/3) for odd prime p > 3. Please let me know by the end of July, 2023 if you'd be interested in collaborating on a paper. Otherwise I would really like to mention your name in the Acknowledgements section.

Comment: Typo: tan(Pi/p), as opposed to tan(Pi/3)

Answer (score 8):

Your conjecture is likely to be true. I was not able to check the details because I couldn't get all the references, but here are the main steps.

The main point is that if there is a Gaussian integer $z$ such that $z^n-z-a=0$ or $z^n+z-a=0$ for some $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, and if $z$ is not an integer ,then $X^n-X-a$ or $X^n+X-a$ has a quadratic monic irreducible factor, namely the minimal polynomial of $z$.

Then, it is enough to understand which quadratic factors may occur in polynomials on the form $X^n\pm X-a$, and check that in each case they are not of the form $X^2-2u X+(u^2+v^2)$ (the minimal polynomial of $u+iv$
when $v\neq0$).

This question seems to be well understood.

In the paper [1] S. Rabinowitz, The Factorization of $x^5\pm x+n$ Math. Mag., 61 (1988), 191–193,

Rabinowitz proved that if $x^n\pm x+n, n\in\mathbb{Z}$ has an irreducible quadratic factor, then $n\in\{\pm 1,\pm 6,\pm 15,\pm 22440,\pm 2959640\}$.

The explicit factorisations are given in the paper (easy to find on the web) , and none of the quadratic factors have the right shape, so this is OK.

For $n>6$, Le proved that if $X^n-X-a$ has
has an irreducible quadratic factor $g$ which is monic,then either $n≡2(mod 6),a=-1$ and $g(x)=x^2-x+1,$ or $n=7,a=±280$ and $g=x^2\pm x+5.$

Once again, this is OK in this case.

Source: [2] M. H. Le, Irreducible quadratic factors of the trinomial $x^n-x-a$ J. Math.
(Wuhan), 24 (2004), 635–637.

I couldn't get the paper, and I have some doubts on the assumption $n>6$. It is maybe $n\geq 6$, i don't know.(ANyway, I think one can manage the case $n= 6$ by hand...)

Apparently, there are similar results for $X^n+X-a$, but I couldn't get the paper nor see the statements of the results.

Source: [3] M. Y. Lin, The irreducible quadratic factor of the trinomial $x^n+x-a$, Math. Appl. (Wuhan), 19 (2006), 656–658.

All in all, I think you conjecture should be true.

If you are able to get a copy of papers [2] and [3], you should be able to check it.